# Shadow DOM - Highlight not working if tabindex used with delegatesFocus

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, shadow-dom

I've noticed that double click text selection stops working for other elements if the `tabindex` attribute is used anywhere inside a shadow DOM with `delegatesFocus: true`.
I can reproduce this in Chrome or Edge.

#### Not working - `tabindex` and `delegatesFocus: true`

```html
<div id="app-root"></div>

<script>
document.querySelector('#app-root').attachShadow({mode: "open", delegatesFocus: true}).innerHTML =
    "<div>Unable to highlight by double clicking</div>\n" +
    "<div tabindex=\"0\">Highlights on double click</div>\n"
</script>
```

#### Working - `tabindex` and `delegatesFocus: false`

```html
<div id="app-root"></div>

<script>
document.querySelector('#app-root').attachShadow({mode: "open"}).innerHTML =
    "<div>Unable to highlight by double clicking</div>\n" +
    "<div tabindex=\"0\">Highlights on double click</div>\n"
</script>
```

#### Working - No `tabindex` and `delegatesFocus: true`

```html
<div id="app-root"></div>

<script>
document.querySelector('#app-root').attachShadow({mode: "open", delegatesFocus: true}).innerHTML =
    "<div>Unable to highlight by double clicking</div>\n" +
    "<div>Highlights on double click</div>\n"
</script>
```

Is my usage of the shadow DOM incorrect?

Comment: shouldn't there be just one``body`` tag in an HTML document? You have bodies all over the place

Comment: There is one other body in the shadow root. This is required as we use Any Design inside the shadow root and it applies it's styles to the body.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue. I think it might be a issue with chromium.

Comment: @YuZhou I agree. I've created a ticket. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1506490#c1

Answer (score -1):

Refactored to Minimal Required Code, double click just works

So there is something in your code that blocks it.

Start with your failing code, line by line refactor it to this code, and see where it goes wrong.

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script>
  app
   .attachShadow({ mode: "open"})
   .innerHTML =
      "<div>Unable to highlight by double clicking</div>\n" +
      "<div>Highlights on double click</div>\n"
</script>
```

Comment: I've simplified the code to the minimal amount. The tabindex in combination with `delegatesFocus` is causing this.